# How to return a specific constructor when using reflection?

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, overloading, ambiguity

I'm reading the following document : [Constructor References](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references)

There is explained how to send a referenced to constructor. But they don't described a situation when there is more than one constructor (overloaded constructor). The following code makes an error in compilation because of *overload resolution ambiguity*:

```
     open  class Animal (val stttt:String, val str:String = "hjm") {
        constructor(number1: Int, _number2: Int) :this("dsa")
        {
            println("runnnnnn")
        }
     }
```

function that gets the constructor as parameter:

```
fun function(factory: () -> Animal) {
    val x: Animal = factory()
}
```

and here is the problem:

```
    function(::Animal)
```

How can i solve this conflict? And how **function** knows which type of constructor it's gets (depends to the constructor, each constructor needs different arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just an incorrect error message. The real problem is that *none* of your constructors match the signature the function requires. Neither of your constructors has zero arguments. In this case you could make your function request a function that has a signature matching one of your constructors:

```
fun function(factory: (String) -> Animal) {
    val x: Animal = factory("foo")
}
```

It is possible to create constructor ambiguity through the use of default arguments. This is a problem even without constructor references, so you should avoid doing it in the first place. The compiler should probably have a warning about that.

Comment: If this were a practical factory function, you would need to pass parameters to it that are required by the constructor. Your example class Animal has a contructor that can be called with one String parameter `stttt` (since the second parameter with a default value can be omitted). So in my example I modified the function so you can pass a constructor that takes a single String parameter.

Comment: @Tefour04, I think i understand. Thank you!